# About Raspberry Pi 3 Power Consumption

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm just bought a new Raspberry Pi 3 (and also 5V,2.5A Power Supply). And I'm totally a fresher to this so before to start using it I have some few question about its power.

I'm now connect my Pi with:

```
1. 1 Screen Monitor (Powered with another Power Supply) connecting through HDMI.
2. 1 Keyboard (USB port).
3. 1 Mouse (USB port).
4. 1 External Drive WD My Passport Ultra (with 3.0 USB cable) (USB port).
```

My question is does my Pi have enough power to handle all this above mentioned devices and if it is, can I use one more USB port for another device such as WD Passport and GPIO for a radiator fan ?.

Thank you for all your helps.

Comment: Yes , It can handle all things.

Comment: @chetanmahajan Thank you for answer my question. You mean that with that Power Supply my Pi can even handle all 4 things mentioned above and also one more USB External Drive and a Radiator Fan ?

Comment: Yes, 5v power direct to send 4 USB port, GPIO pins, and the external part, but only use 5v things, not then higher. Hope It's helpfull.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @chetanmahajan

Answer (score 0):

When your Pi will have not enough power for all peripherals you will see small yellow flash on screen. Then you should upgrade your power supply.

[image]

Comment: On screen ? You mean yellow led flashing on raspberry?

Comment: @QuangHuyChu it is written here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/

Comment: ohhh got it. Thank you very much.